# Mapping a key to a command with no keybind in Vimperator

Tags: vimperator

I've been trying to map '<<' and '>>' to ':tabmove -1' and ':tabmove +1' respectively. I want the '<<' and the '>>' to execute those commands. The problem is that whether I use :map, :nmap, :noremap or any variation, the mapping for '<<' doesn't work (I haven't attempted a mapping for '>>' for that reason). From what I've read in the vimperator manual, mapping is usually done between one key/key combination and another key/key combination that already does something. :tabmove doesn't have a key assigned to it; it's just a command. So, I don't know if it's even possible to directly map a command to a key. If it is, how is it done? If this isn't possible, is there an alternative to simulate this?

Comment: Did you remember carriage return?  That is, did you try :nmap  << :tabmove -1<CR>?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I *just* tried this, with the carriage return, and it worked! I didn't even think of that; I thought it would just take the command without needing a carriage return to 'execute it' I guess. Thanks for the assistance.